# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class"

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, extern, lnk2019, lnk2001

I've a header file having a "extern class definition" in it. Both these header file and class are in different C++ assembly. Now there is a class in different C++ assembly which is trying to access this "extern" class functions but there are all sorts of linker errors such as `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol " class LMSystem LM"(?LM@@3VLMSystem@@A)`,`LNK2019` etc.

## Following is the code snippet:for CPP file

/*This header file contains the extern reference*/

```
#include "../lm/lm.h"



BOOL FDInitHW (void) 
{ 
   char pFileName[TALLY_MAX_PATH];

   ASSERT(0 != g_pFdbPath);
   strcpy(pFileName, g_pFdbPath);
   strcat(pFileName, FILENAME_HW_KB);

   return SUCCESS == LM.LMIOListReadSelective(pFileName, 
                           LMIO_READREPLACE, FDGetSelectListPtrArray()); 
}
```

## Contents of Lm.h

```
class LMSystem
{
public:   
   LMSystem();
   ~LMSystem();

   // getting a specific list
   short  LMIOListReadSelective(char *fname, unsigned short readflags, LIST_SELECTOR* select_array[]);
}; 
    extern LMSystem LM;  // the library global LMSytem
```

So can you help me in resolving this linker error?
I think it has to do something with project properties as the old assembly developed in VC++ 6.0 is working fine and even in this Win32 C++ assembly,which I'm creating in VS2012,I'm able to go to definition of the `LMSystem` class using F12 or Intellisense but ideally it should point me to the variable in `LM.H` header file. 
I've seen many post telling how to use functions of one type defined in different C++.dll in another C++ .dll. There are many project level settings changes but it doesn't always give me the correct results. So if anybody can give me a solution to this issue then it will be great help.

Comment: Where is the class `LMSystem` defined?

Comment: Are you linking this LM library to your project? BTW, there is no such thing as "C++ assemblies".

Comment: @Peter:LMSystem class is defined in Lm.h header file. Please refer to edited code snippet. Marius: I meant Win32 C++ dll

Answer (score 1):

Instance of `LM` needs to be created somewhere and your linker must be able to find it. For example add `LMSystem LM;` to  **one**  of your source (`.cpp`) files

Comment: It is already getting created in a .cpp class,so the _declspec dllexport problem is solved but there is one other external linking error.